# Atan2 rotational stutter in Canvas + SVG path

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, svg

Previously I built a motion path with `svg`, but noticed rendering performance on mobile wasn't too great. I decided to convert the motion path to `canvas`, which would give me better performance.

I opted to create a clone of my `canvas` path with `svg` so that I could use the `getPointAtLength()` and `getTotalLength()` methods to get the corresponding *x*, *y* values of sampled points and the *length* of the `canvas` path.

The problem is that the value returned after sampling with `getPointAtLength` seems to result in irregular rotation.

I have a hunch this has to do with the differences in positions I am sampling from along the path using the `getPointAtLength()` method.

How can I fix the value that is returned from `atan2` so that it results in smooth linear rotation along the path?

```js
var canvas = document.body.querySelector('.loader__canvas');
var source = document.body.querySelector('.loader__source');

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var angle;
var speed = 0.5;
var deltaX;
var deltaY;
var nextCoords;
var prevCoords;
var offset = 0;
var distance = source.getTotalLength();

render();

function render() {

  // Reset the loop once offset exceeds the path's distance
  if (offset >= distance) {
    offset = 1 * speed;
  } else {
    offset += 1 * speed;
  }

  // Clear the canvas from all previous operations
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw the loop that the object is attached to
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 300);
  ctx.arc(300, 300, 50, Math.PI, -Math.PI / 2, true);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 250);
  ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, Math.PI / 2, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 250);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ddd';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Save the current transformation matrix for future reset
  ctx.save();

  // Calculate coordinates and angle for the object,
  // if prevCoords is undefined: assign initial values
  prevCoords = nextCoords || source.getPointAtLength(offset);
  nextCoords = source.getPointAtLength(offset);
  angle = Math.atan2(
    (nextCoords.y - prevCoords.y), (nextCoords.x - prevCoords.x)
  ) + (Math.PI / 2);

  // Apply transforms
  ctx.translate(nextCoords.x, nextCoords.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  // Draw path object
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#f63';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Restore transforms
  ctx.restore();

  // Loop
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.loader__canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.loader__source {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="loader__canvas" width="500" height="500">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path class="loader__source" d="m250,250v50a50,50,0,1,0,50,-50h-100a50,50,0,1,1,50,-50z" />
  </svg>
</canvas>
```

### Updated example

With the help and suggestion of [Blindman67's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34235507/1113913), I increased the offset, in combination with the `%` operator on prevCoords. `Math.atan2()` seems to work fine now and the rotation along the path is smooth.

However I would like to know why an offset of 1 causes so much oscillation and an offset of 10 does not?

```js
var canvas = document.body.querySelector('.loader__canvas');
var source = document.body.querySelector('.loader__source');

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var angle;
var speed = 5;
var deltaX;
var deltaY;
var offset = 0;
var nextCoordsPlug;
var prevCoordsPlug;
var nextCoordsSocket;
var prevCoordsSocket;
var distance = source.getTotalLength();

render();

function render() {

  // Reset the loop once offset exceeds the path's distance
  if (offset >= distance) {
    offset = 1 * speed;
  } else {
    offset += 1 * speed;
  }

  // Clear the canvas from all previous operations
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.setLineDash([source.getTotalLength() - 50, 50]);
  ctx.lineDashOffset = -(offset + 40);

  // Draw the loop that the object is attached to
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 20;
  ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 300);
  ctx.arc(300, 300, 50, Math.PI, -Math.PI / 2, true);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 250);
  ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, Math.PI / 2, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 250);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#f63';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Save the current transformation matrix for future reset
  ctx.save();

  // Calculate coordinates and angle for the object,
  // use the remainder to extend the point past the distance
  prevCoordsPlug = source.getPointAtLength((offset + 10) % distance);
  nextCoordsPlug = source.getPointAtLength(offset);
  angle = Math.atan2(
    (nextCoordsPlug.y - prevCoordsPlug.y), (nextCoordsPlug.x - prevCoordsPlug.x)
  ) - (Math.PI / 2);

  // Apply transforms
  ctx.translate(nextCoordsPlug.x, nextCoordsPlug.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  // Draw path object
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI);
  ctx.rect(-12, -20, 8, 20);
  ctx.rect(4, -20, 8, 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#f63';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Restore and save previous transforms
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();

  prevCoordsSocket = source.getPointAtLength((offset + 45) % distance);
  nextCoordsSocket = source.getPointAtLength((offset + 35) % distance);
  angle = Math.atan2(
    (nextCoordsSocket.y - prevCoordsSocket.y), (nextCoordsSocket.x - prevCoordsSocket.x)
  ) + (Math.PI / 2);

  // Apply transforms
  ctx.translate(nextCoordsSocket.x, nextCoordsSocket.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  // Draw path object
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#f63';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Restore transforms
  ctx.restore();

  // Loop
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.loader__canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateZ(0);
}
.loader__source {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="loader__canvas" width="500" height="500">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path class="loader__source" d="m250,250v50a50,50,0,1,0,50,-50h-100a50,50,0,1,1,50,-50z" />
  </svg>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pixel locations**

I am unsure as to why this is happening, though I used some flawed logic and accidentally found a solution. To combat this find the point a little further from the offset. I added 4 pixels and got the previous location `prevCoords = source.getPointAtLength((offset + 4) % distance);` I looked ahead to ensure that a negative offset would not mess up the start.

Even moving the offset the direction was still a little rough. So I added a simple smoothing algorithum to the angle. Keeping a separate value `angleReal` to display the smoothed angle and a `angleDelta` to smooth the motion. There is a `drag` and `acceleration` component that determine the behaviour. Different values will effect the smoothing. If `drag` has values over 0.5 the smoothing will start to oscillate (sometimes a nice effect but not wanted in this case)

There was also the problem that `atan2` return the angle `-Math.PI` to `Math.PI` the smoothing sees `-Math.PI` and `Math.PI` as two different angles, but they are the same so I added a test to make sure that the transition from `-Math.PI` to `Math.PI` did not make the smoothing spin the object.

Below is your code with the bits I modified to smooth out the object directio. It is not the only solution, but it is the one I would use for animation.

**Update**

On further investigation I have found that the function `getPointAtLength` is at fault.

Using the following code (in context of your code) I compare the distance give by `getTotalLength` to the distance covered by sampling the path using `getPointAtLength`

```
  var distance = source.getTotalLength(); // get the distance along the path;
  var next;         // next point 
  var dist = 0;     // the measured distance
  var step = 1;     // path sample rate
  var last = source.getPointAtLength(0);      // get the first point

  for(var i = step; i < distance; i+= step){  // sample points 
      next = source.getPointAtLength(i);      // get a point at offset i

      // get and sum the distance between the two samples 
      dist += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(next.x-last.x,2)+Math.pow(next.y-last.y,2));
      last = next;   // move the current sample to the last
  }
  // sample the last remaining bit 
  next = source.getPointAtLength(distance);
  // add that distance.
  dist += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(next.x-last.x,2)+Math.pow(next.y-last.y,2));
  // show result
  console.log("Measured:"+dist.toFixed(2)+" Given:"+distance.toFixed(2))
```

The results of sampling at 1, 0.1, and 0.01

- 674.64 for sample step of 1
- 833.49 for sample step of 0.1
- 944.37 for sample step of 0.01

Distance given by `source.getTotalLength()` is 671.31.

One would expect the error to reduce as the sampling distance decreased, but it increases, pointing strongly to an error within the function 'getPointAtLength' and would explain your inaccuracies when calculating the direction.  The function `getPointAtLength` is not returning a point precisely on the path.

```js
var canvas = document.body.querySelector('.loader__canvas');
var source = document.body.querySelector('.loader__source');

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var angle;

// Blindman67 change start---------------------------------
var angleReal;
var angleDelta;
var drag = 0.1;
var acceleration = 0.9;
// Blindman67 change end---------------------------------

var speed = 0.5;
var deltaX;
var deltaY;
var nextCoords;
var prevCoords;
var offset = 0;
var distance = source.getTotalLength();

render();

function render() {

  // Reset the loop once offset exceeds the path's distance
  if (offset >= distance) {
    offset = 1 * speed;
  } else {
    offset += 1 * speed;
  }

  // Clear the canvas from all previous operations
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw the loop that the object is attached to
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 300);
  ctx.arc(300, 300, 50, Math.PI, -Math.PI / 2, true);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 250);
  ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, Math.PI / 2, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(250, 250);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ddd';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Save the current transformation matrix for future reset
  ctx.save();

  // Calculate coordinates and angle for the object,
  // if prevCoords is undefined: assign initial values

  // Blindman67 change start---------------------------------
  // get the offset a larger pixel distance
  prevCoords = source.getPointAtLength((offset+4)%distance);
  // Blindman67 change end ---------------------------------

  nextCoords = source.getPointAtLength(offset);
  angle = Math.atan2(
    (nextCoords.y - prevCoords.y), (nextCoords.x - prevCoords.x)
  ) + (Math.PI / 2);

  // Blindman67 change start---------------------------------
  if(angleDelta === undefined){  // if not set set up init vals
     angleDelta = 0;
     angleReal = angle;
  }
  if(Math.abs(angle-angleReal) > Math.PI){
     angleReal = angle;
  }
  // add smoothing to the angle
  angleDelta += (angle-angleReal)*acceleration;
  angleDelta *= drag;
  angleReal += angleDelta;
  // Apply transforms
  ctx.translate(nextCoords.x, nextCoords.y);
  ctx.rotate(angleReal+Math.PI);
  // Blindman67 change end ---------------------------------

  // Draw path object
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#f63';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Restore transforms
  ctx.restore();

  // Loop
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.loader__canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.loader__source {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="loader__canvas" width="500" height="500">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path class="loader__source" d="m250,250v50a50,50,0,1,0,50,-50h-100a50,50,0,1,1,50,-50z" />
  </svg>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified some of the code you provided, but you pointed me in the right direction. Logging `getPointAtLength()` does seem to give me the coordinates in float distance as is described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement)

Using the `%` operator to get the coordinates _beyond_ the path's distance is a great idea. It all seems to work great now, the oscillating movement is gone, unfortunately I do not fully understand why.

Increasing the `speed` variable also somehow removed the oscillating movement at certain points along the path.

Comment: I had better fix my answer as i just made a guess that the coords were ints.. If MDN and your logging show it is not so then its so.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help so far! I updated my post with another example that is usable now. 

The only question that remains is why `Math.atan2(y,x) ` gave me such oscillating rotation while sampling points _until_ the offset on `prevCoords` was increased.

Even decreasing the value of `10` that is added to _offset_ on the line `prevCoordsPlug = source.getPointAtLength((offset + 10) % distance)` seems to reintroduce the oscillation.

I would love to know what was causing it, I'll mark your answer as being the solution.

Comment: It is midnight here so I will get back to it in the morning.

Comment: Many thanks, have a good weekend! If you can't figure it out, I'll mark it as solved. Thanks for all the effort so far!

Comment: I have found that the error is in `source.getPointAtLength` and have updated the answer to show how I came to that conclusion.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer. I marked your answer as the solution to the problem. I used your code to render the output to an `<svg> path` element so I could examine the path close up by zooming in. I believe [this illustrates](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hp0yI.png) why the attached object was rotating so much.